# Problema cada vez que ejecuto aplicación : IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: android, android-studio

últimamente he tenido el siguiente problema en *Android Studio*, en todos los proyectos que tengo y los nuevos, cree uno y también da el error al ejecutar.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:433)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at co.com.yogo.kemion.actividades.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5010)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4767)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:764)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:531)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

La solución *troll* que he utilizado es:

1. Limpiar o recompilar proyecto, y así si va.
2. O también usar 2 terminales, compilar en 1, y la siguiente vez
   compilar en otro.

Si ejecuto 2 veces seguidas en el mismo da error.

Muchas gracias, por su ayuda en este asunto.

Comment: ¿es posible que la instancia del JDK no sea encontrada en los equipos donde está intentando ejecutar/compilar la aplicación? [fuente](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: Por favor agrega en tu pregunta el contenido de tus folders `/libs` y tus `gradle.build`,

Comment: Voy a mostrar la estructura, pero igual como mencione arriba, aparece en todos los proyectos incluso los nuevos.
Creo un proyecto nuevo, con una actividad en blanco y solo un mensaje de ¡Hello word! Y sale el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes alguna librería en tu proyecto que esta definida más de una vez, ya sea dentro de `/libs` o dentro de tu `gradle.build`, este error se corrige usando las últimas versiones del plugin Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

dentro de tu build.gradle también puedes definir la propiedad `multiDexEnabled true`:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

para evitar este error.

Comment: Este "multiDexEnabled true" Me sirvió y ya no me da error, en la carpeta /libs no hay nada, no utilizo librerías, más que las que trae un proyecto en blanco que se acaba de crear, solo tiene una actividad con mensaje de “Hello word”. 

Pero ya se solucionó, gracias.